# Distributed singleton service for failover

Tags: algorithm, singleton, distributed-system

I have an abstract question.

I need a service with fault tolerance. The service only can only be running on one node at a time. This is the key.

With two connected nodes: A and B.

- If A is running the service, B must be waiting.
- If A is turned off, B should detect this and start the service.
- If A is turned on again, A should wait and don't run the service.
- etc. (If B is turned off, A starts, if A is turned off B starts)

I have think about heartbeat protocol for sync the status of the nodes and detect timeouts, however there are a lot of race conditions.

I can add a third node with a global lock, but I'm not sure about how to do this.

Anybody know any well-known algorithm to do this? Or better Is there any open source software that lets me control this kind of things?

Thanks

Comment: Tell us  little more what your services do. What are the exclusive resources? Is it input or output that must be exclusive? Why not running parallel in a redundant fashion?

Comment: There are dozens of examples of exclusive resources: an external service that supports only a single connection per client, a ticket service, a service that handle some of IoT (hardware)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can provide some sort of a shared memory between nodes, then there is the classical algorithm that resolves this problem, called [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm).

It is based on two additional variables, called `flag` and `turn`. `Turn` is an integer variable whose value represents an index of node that is allowed to be active at the moment. In other words, `turn=1` indicates that node no 1 has right to be active, and other node should wait. In other words, it is his turn to be active - that's where the name comes from.

`Flag` is a boolean array where `flag[i]` indicates that i-th node declares itself as ready for service. In your setup, `flag[i]=false` means that i-th node is down. Key part of the algorithm is that a node which is ready for service (i.e. `flag[i] = true`) has to wait until he obtains `turn`.

Algorithm is originally developed for resolving a problem of execution a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) without conflict. However, in your case a critical section is simply running the service. You just have to ensure that before i-th node is turned off, it sets `flag[i]` to false. This is definitely a tricky part because if a node crashes, it obviously cannot set any value. I would go here with a some sort of a heartbeat.

Regarding the open source software that resolves similar problems, try searching for "cluster failover". Read about [Google's Paxos](http://research.google.com/archive/paxos_made_live.pdf) and [Google FileSystem](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf). There are plenty of solutions, but if you want to implement something by yourself, I would try Peterson's algorithm.